# Difference between a static field and a injected singleton in controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, static, concurrentdictionary

What is the difference between a static `Dictionary` field, a (static or non-static?) [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-2.2) field, and a dependency injected singleton service in a controller in ASP.NET Core?

A static dictionary.

```csharp
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static IDictionary<string, string> _dictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

A (static or non-static?) `ConcurrentDictionary`.

```csharp
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> _dictionary =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
}
```

A `Dictionary` property inside a dependency injected singleton service.

```csharp
// Startup.cs
services.AddSingleton<HomeService>(); // Dependency injection

// HomeService.cs
public class HomeService
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> MyDictionary { get; set; } =
        new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

// HomeController.cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private HomeService _service;

    public HomeController(HomeService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _service.MyDictionary.Add("foo", "bar");
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

What is the difference? How are they different from each other? Is any approach favored over the other?

Comment: I depends entirely on what you're actually doing. However, statics, in general, should be avoided. That said, the point of injecting a service doesn't have anything to do with this. That dictionary represents something. It's domain logic that's almost assuredly not *controller* logic. As such, how that dictionary is utilized and its very existence is something that should be factored out of the controller into a class.

Comment: My two cents: Static will be hanging during the whole app lifecycle.. so you should avoid it They can cause memory leaks (it becomes what's known as a `A GC Root`), The nonstatic is okay - It will be gone once your controller is deallocated, since it's a field inside it. Maybe this helps: https://michaelscodingspot.com/find-fix-and-avoid-memory-leaks-in-c-net-8-best-practices/

Comment: @jpgrassi But I want to share the dictionary among different HTTP requests. Each HTTP request creates a new instance of the controller.

Comment: @HenkHolterman No. The difference between static dictionary field and a dictionary inside a service obtained as a singleton.

Comment: Let’s step back for a moment. What is the purpose of the dictionary? Is it for some sort of configuration?

Comment: @jpgrassi No, it is for holding state. One action writes to the dictionary, and another action reads from the dictionary. It is supposed to a shared state between requests that is not tied to any user.

Comment: Hum.. I would go with another approach then. Have you considered something like Redis? I wouldn't share state like this in a static dictionary.. it's not scalable especially if you have multiple instances of your app running, say like behind a LB.

Comment: @jpgrassi Good point. I did not consider that. You are right, it is not scalable across multiple instances. As I am curious, I am still seeking some answers to the questions I posed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [jpgrassi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689390/jpgrassi) in the comment, having a static field inside a Controller is not a good idea due to that it does not scale across multiple instances of the application running behind a load balancer.

The proper way to do is in ASP.NET Core is to use [distributed caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed) with the `IDistributedCache` interface which allows different implementations such as in-memory or Redis, etc.

```csharp
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;

    public HomeController(IDistributedCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var currentTimeUTC = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
        byte[] encodedCurrentTimeUTC = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(currentTimeUTC);
        var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        await _cache.SetAsync("cachedTimeUTC", encodedCurrentTimeUTC, options);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```